# jquery ui slider. Help to correct please

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

help please to fix my problem. i am newby in jquery ui. And have tried to create jquery slider:
http://jsfiddle.net/InviS/LYE8B/4/
But it outstep my  in right position (see example). how can i limit the slider?

Comment: Have you tried changing the max value? See [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-max) for all of the options.

Comment: Max value won't help, as it doesn't control the appearance of the slider at all.

Comment: Could you enter this as a bug at the jQuery site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/NAC7b/10/.

It's a bit hacky, but I wrap the slider within a parent `<div>`, and give the slider a max-width of `93%`. Here's my changed CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 129px;
}

#scroll{
    width: 93%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
$('#scroll').slider({animate: true}).bind('slidestop',function(e,ui){
    //alert(ui.value);
}).wrap('<div id="wrapper" />');
```

Comment: That's much cleaner code than mine ;) I'm amazed that this isn't implemented/fixed in jQuery UI, as it seems to be a pretty mature project by now...